# how to install magento2

Tags: composer-php, magento2

Is there a way to install magento2 using composer? I found a command

```
 composer create-project magento/community-edition ./ -s dev --prefer-dist
```

but is that somehow possible with just a composer.json and then

```
 composer install
```

? I tried this:

```
{
  "name": "asfasf",
  "require": {
    "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "0.1.0-alpha89"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "http://packages.magento.com/"
    }
  ],
  "extra": {
    "magento-root-dir": "htdocs",
    "magento-deploystrategy": "copy"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

but that throws an error

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                      
Your configuration does not allow connections to http://packages.magento.com/packages.json.
```

any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please check firewall

Comment: ...what firewall do you mean ?

Comment: refer this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)

Comment: yeah that's not the problem